# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'/ 'string'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm following a tutorial and I'm having an error on a map I don't know why, it seems to me that I'm doing it right

**Here is my List**

```
var questions = [
    {
      'questiontext': "Questão 1",
      'answer': [
        {'text': 'Black', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Red', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Green', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'White', 'score': 1},
      ]
    },
    {
      'questiontext': "Questão 2",
      'answer': {
        {'text': 'Rabbit', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'Snake', 'score': 11},
        {'text': 'Elephant', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Lion', 'score': 9},
      },
    },
    {
      'questiontext': "Questão 3",
      'answer': {
        {'text': 'Peter', 'score': 1},
        {'text': 'Paul', 'score': 1},
        {'text': 'Max', 'score': 1},
      },
    }
  ];
```

**My dart code**

```
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
        
...(questions[0]['answer'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => textfunction(answer['score']), answer['text']);
        }).toList()
```

Errors

> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'String'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
>
> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'int'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

[image]

I don't know what's wrong. I've already tried to switch to dynamic and it keeps giving an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but answer 1 is a list, the others are sets [ ] vs { }

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it this way :
`answer['score'] as int` & `answer['text'] as String`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but returns this error `type '_CompactLinkedHashSet<Map<String, Object>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, Object>>' in type cast`

Comment: Also check what @w461 said, seems also an issue.